# Too Many Redirects on OpenShift after push

Tags: node.js, openshift, haproxy

I have a node.js application running on openshift. After testing my code on a local environment I pushed it up to my instance on openshift. After doing so, I went to check those changes on the public site and my browser reported that I was getting too many redirects. I tried to look at my haproxy status and even that was getting too many redirects.

I have done some investigation and here is what I've found:

- I checked my nodejs logs and my node server started successfully (no errors)
- I've ssh'd into my machine and ran `curl -vvv $OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP:8080` and I was returned my index.html as I should.
- When I run `curl -vvv http://minutepolitics-minutepolitics.rhcloud.com/` I get this response:

RESPONSE:

```
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Trying 54.81.203.46...
Connected to minutepolitics-minutepolitics.rhcloud.com (54.81.203.46) port 80 (#0)
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
Host: minutepolitics-minutepolitics.rhcloud.com
Accept: */*
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 23 Oct 2014 03:26:06 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) is not blacklisted
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Vary: Host
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Location: http://minutepolitics-minutepolitics.rhcloud.com/
Connection: close
Accept-Ranges: none
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Closing connection 0
```

Also, when I ssh into my machine and run `/etc/init.d/haproxy start` the output is:  `Starting haproxy: [ALERT] 294/230821 (134951) : Starting frontend main: cannot bind socket [FAILED]`

From here, I don't know what to do or try to get this working again.

Any and all help will be greatly apprecaited! Thanks!!

Comment: What's it redirecting to? Try finding out which routes the loop is in. Also if you have express static routes configured try supplying it `{ redirect : false }` option.

Comment: UPDATE: I restarted my node server and haproxy gear and the issue has resolved itself. I'm still concerned however because I don't know the root cause of the error.